# Memory Leak and Weak References

Tags: .net, vb.net, memory-leaks, weak-references

I'm having an issue which looks like a memory leak in one of my applications (the application uses more memory over time, an after about a week of work it hangs).

I've detected and fixed some leaks related to classes I've written (comparing heap dumps taken with sos.dll revealed them quickly), and those no longer increase in number.

Currently, the only thing that dramatically increases over time are `WeakReference` instances, which increase at a steady rate of 1,000 new `WeakReference` instances per minute.

My code doesn't use `WeakReference` directly, I never create those myself.

What could cause so many `WeakReference` instances to be created?

I'm using VB.NET, Visual Studio 2008 and .NET 3.5

Comment: Are you using an ORM? (like Entity Framework, Linq-to-sql, NHibernate) Is your a Web App?

Comment: have you tried using Microsoft's [CLR profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273) to see what is holding the references?

Comment: My app is a local application (communicates with other devices over serial port or TCP sockets). The only ORM I use is LINQ2SQL, and that is a secondary function that isn't being used often (isn't being called unless the user specifically calls that functionality). I can cut the ORM part completely out of the app for testing if you think it could be it.

Comment: @Marc, no I have not, I'll go learn how to do that right now, didn't know it is possible!

Comment: Since you're familiar with SOS already, have you tried using the "gcroots" command on a few of these WeakReferences to determine what's holding them (and hence probably also what's creating them in the first place)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is a fairly infamous leak in VB.NET assemblies.  It is caused by weak references that keep track of events that are declared with the WithEvents keyword.  This tracking is done to support Edit and Continue.  It leaks one instance of WeakReference for every one WithEvents event declared in a class.  The debugger needs to be attached to release those WeakReference objects.

The workaround is simple.  Ship the Release build, not the Debug build.

Comment: Has this been fixed? Also, can you provide some further details as to why and how this happens? The only useful thing I turned up while Googling was this answer.