# .NET memory leak - System.WeakReference objects accumulate

Tags: .net, vb.net, memory-leaks, windbg, sos

I have a service written in VB.NET which leaks memory.  The memory grows even when it's not doing much.  It starts out using about 29,000 K in the task manager, and after a number of hours, depending on how busy it is, it grows to 500,000K or sometimes over 1,000,000K.  For some customers, this causes memory issues on their servers.  The service has an auto-restart function which will restart the service once a day, but sometimes this isn't enough, and we need to use a net stop/start from the windows scheduler several times a day.

PerfMon shows that the "Gen 2 heap size" continues to grow while the serivce is running, while other heap numbers don't.  Of course, the "# Bytes in all heaps" grows as well, as it includes that number.

When I create a dump file of the running service, open it in windbg, load SOS, and run "!dumpheap -stat" on it, the largest number of objects are of class "System.WeakReference".  In the example I'm looking at now, there are 4,542,785 of these, out of a total of 4,636,227 objects.

From what I have read, these objects are used by the GC to hold references to objects it is working with, is that how this appears?  If so, why wouldn't it also GC these when it's done with them?  Is there a way to see what object the WeakReference object is holding on to?

Thanks!

Comment: The `WeakReference` class has a `Target` property that holds the referenced object. Does your service make use of `WeakReference` a lot?

Comment: No, we don't declare it at all.  From what I can tell, the GC is using these in its processing.

Comment: WeakReference is used by the System.Web.Caching among other classes in the framework. Can you check what holds the WeakReference rooted?

Answer (score 2):

The `WeakReference` will hold a weak reference to an object, but the reference to the `WeakReference`-instance is hard, hence: if you hold a lot of dead (`IsAlive` is `false`) references they will still use memory.

Make sure that you do not store you `WeakReference`s in a list or store them some other way for eternity.

**Edit**:
If you are not holding the references yourself, it could be that this is caused by [issues with `WithEvents` in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7920482/167251). In short, compile your application in Release mode and the issue should be fixed [according to Microsoft.](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=919481)

Comment: To clarify, I don't declare anything as WeakReference.  From what I can tell, the GC is using these in its processing.

Comment: Run !sos.gcroot on a sampling of the WeakReference objects.  You can also run !sosex.bhi to build an index, and then run !mroot on a sampling of the WeakReference objects.

Comment: I do use WithEvents, so it sounds like it could be related to this.  However, in the linked answer above, it implies that a Release build will not have the leak, but it appears that everything on this service is built as release.  Is there anything else to look for, that might prevent the WithEvents from doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is invalid usage of WeakReference class in code. 
To locate code, constructing that instances, use some profiling tool, that can trace entire object lifetime from point of allocation ( dotTrace Memory for example).
Someone forgot to clean Dead weak reference instances from some collection.
Find and fix.